# Choosing specific table to submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am currently calling tables using php in order to show pending purchase requests. An admin will either approve or deny these requests based on the contents of each table. Each table will have a unique identifier and this is how they are divided. I am trying to determine how I can approve/deny each table individually, but I'm new to jQuery. I've used it before in a similar manner but can't seem to find a solution for what I am trying to do.

[image]

Right now, I'm just trying to set up an alert to make sure that the function is working properly.

PHP code showing table format (code is in a while loop):

```
echo "<form method='POST' onsubmit='moveTable(this)'>
            <table id='pendingTable'>
                <tbody>
                    <tr style='background-color:$bgcolor'>
                        <input type='hidden' value='".$RNrow['request_number']."'>
                        <td id='name'>".$PRrow['ItemName']."</td>
                        <td>".$PRrow['ItemDesc']."</td>
                        <td>".$PRrow['BrandName']."</td>
                        <td>".$PRrow['ManNum']."</td>
                        <td>".$PRrow['NSN']."</td>
                        <td>".$PRrow['ItemCost']."</td>
                        <td>".$PRrow['Qty']."</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>";
<input type='submit' value='Approve' onclick=\"return confirm ('Are you sure you want to approve this request?')\">                     
<input style='margin-left:5px' type='submit' value='Deny' onclick=\"return confirm ('Are you sure you want to deny this request?')\">
```

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function moveTable(){
            $('#pendingTable tr').each(function(){

            alert('hello');
        });
        }
    </script>
```

The information from these tables would then be moved to an 'approved/denied' mysql table. I figure it may have to do with the uniqueness of the table id but haven't found a way around that. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use id as it is supposed to be unique within the DOM, you can use classes instead like this:

```
echo "<form method='POST' onsubmit='moveTable(this)'>
        <table class='pendingTable'>
            <tbody>
                <tr style='background-color:$bgcolor'>
                    <input type='hidden' value='".$RNrow['request_number']."'>
                    <td id='name'>".$PRrow['ItemName']."</td>
                    <td>".$PRrow['ItemDesc']."</td>
                    <td>".$PRrow['BrandName']."</td>
                    <td>".$PRrow['ManNum']."</td>
                    <td>".$PRrow['NSN']."</td>
                    <td>".$PRrow['ItemCost']."</td>
                    <td>".$PRrow['Qty']."</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>";
<input type='submit' value='Approve' onclick=\"return confirm ('Are you sure you want to approve this request?')\">                     
<input style='margin-left:5px' type='submit' value='Deny' onclick=\"return confirm ('Are you sure you want to deny this request?')\">

<script type="text/javascript">
    function moveTable(form){
        $(form).find('.pendingTable tr').each(function(){

        alert('hello');
    });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This still didn't return the alert. When I take out the .each part it will return, but once I try to do it for each row it fails.

Answer (score 0):

You can paste this entire script into one PHP script and you should be able to see how it passes the table id via ajax to the script at the bottom of the page. Give it a try!

```
<?php if (!isset($_POST['doAjaxAction'])) { ?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Dev Doc</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<style>
    form {
        margin-bottom: 50px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$RNrow['request_number'] = '123';
$RNrow['ItemName'] = 'ItemName';
$RNrow['ItemDesc'] = 'ItemDesc';
$RNrow['BrandName'] = 'BrandName';
$RNrow['ManNum'] = 'ManNum';
$RNrow['NSN'] = 'NSN';
$RNrow['ItemCost'] = 'ItemCost';
$RNrow['Qty'] = 'Qty';
$bgcolor = 'grey'
?>
<form method='POST'>
    <table id='<?php echo $RNrow['request_number'] ?>' class="pendingTable">
        <tbody>
        <tr style='background-color:<?php echo $bgcolor; ?>'>
            <input type='hidden' value='<?php echo $RNrow['request_number'] ?>'>
            <td id = 'name'>"<?php echo $RNrow['ItemName'] ?>"</td>
            <td>"<?php echo $RNrow['ItemDesc'] ?>"</td>
            <td>"<?php echo $RNrow['BrandName'] ?>"</td>
            <td>"<?php echo $RNrow['ManNum'] ?>"</td>
            <td>"<?php echo $RNrow['NSN'] ?>"</td>
            <td>"<?php echo $RNrow['ItemCost'] ?>"</td>
            <td>"<?php echo $RNrow['Qty'] ?>"</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        <input type='submit' value='Approve' onclick="moveTable(<?php echo $RNrow['request_number'] ?>, 'Approve')">
        <input style='margin-left:5px' type='submit' value='Deny' onclick="moveTable(<?php echo $RNrow['request_number'] ?>, 'Deny')">
    </table>
</form>

<?php
$RNrow['request_number'] = '456';
$RNrow['ItemName'] = 'ItemName2';
$RNrow['ItemDesc'] = 'ItemDesc2';
$RNrow['BrandName'] = 'BrandName2';
$RNrow['ManNum'] = 'ManNum2';
$RNrow['NSN'] = 'NSN2';
$RNrow['ItemCost'] = 'ItemCost2';
$RNrow['Qty'] = 'Qty2';
$bgcolor = 'lightblue'
?>
<form method='POST'>
    <table id='<?php echo $RNrow['request_number'] ?>' class="pendingTable">
        <tbody>
        <tr style='background-color:<?php echo $bgcolor; ?>'>
            <input type='hidden' value='<?php echo $RNrow['request_number'] ?>'>
            <td id = 'name'>"<?php echo $RNrow['ItemName'] ?>"</td>
            <td>"<?php echo $RNrow['ItemDesc'] ?>"</td>
            <td>"<?php echo $RNrow['BrandName'] ?>"</td>
            <td>"<?php echo $RNrow['ManNum'] ?>"</td>
            <td>"<?php echo $RNrow['NSN'] ?>"</td>
            <td>"<?php echo $RNrow['ItemCost'] ?>"</td>
            <td>"<?php echo $RNrow['Qty'] ?>"</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        <input type='submit' value='Approve' onclick="moveTable(<?php echo $RNrow['request_number'] ?>, 'Approve')">
        <input style='margin-left:5px' type='submit' value='Deny' onclick="moveTable(<?php echo $RNrow['request_number'] ?>, 'Deny')">
    </table>
</form>



<script>
    function moveTable(id, action) {
        //Opens OK or Cancel Dialog
        if (confirm('Are you sure you want to approve this request?')) {
            //Hit F12 in your browser to the console. This shows what passed in
            alert('ID Sent: ' + id, ' -- Action: ' + action);
            //Posts ID and Action to self, with 'doAjaxAction' set to 1, so only the php script at bottom executes during AJAX call
            $.post('<?php echo basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>',
                {
                    //seen as $_POST['id'] and $_POST['action'] to script at the bottom
                    doAjaxAction: '1',
                    id: id,
                    action: action
                },
                //This function gives us the data returned from approve_deny.php
                function (data, status) {
                    // 'data' returns 'DID SOMETHING'
                    // 'status' returns status of ajax call
                    alert("Data Sent: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
                    if (status === 'success') {
                        //Removes the order from the page. Can change this to grey it out, shrink it, etc
                        alert('AJAX call was a.. ' + status);
                        // $("#" + id + "\"").empty();
                    }
                });
        }
        //If user changes mind, and clicks cancel on confirm
        else {
            alert('Action Cancelled.')
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>

<?php } ?>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['doAjaxAction']) && $_POST['doAjaxAction'] == '1') {
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $action = $_POST['action'];

    if ($action == 'Approve') {
        echo "APPROVED ID # " . $_POST['id'] . " do something with passed ID " . PHP_EOL;
    }
    if ($action == 'Deny') {
        echo "DENIED ID # " . $_POST['id'] . " do something with passed ID " . PHP_EOL;
    }
    echo "DID SOMETHING AT END" . PHP_EOL;
}
?>
```

Comment: I've plugged everything in and I keep getting this 'unexpected end of input' error I think its coming from the 'Approve' and 'Deny' buttons but cant adjust them to fix the problem

Comment: It doesnt seem to let me add parameters to the onclick event on the submit button.

Comment: The code is more of a guide. Since I don't have your full source code, you'll have to figure out where the above code fits into your application.

The code was also missing the ';'s after the echo statements. Give that a look

Comment: Any luck? I edited the code to include proper semicolons.

Comment: I did see initially where the semicolons were missing and added those, but still throwing the error. The code you provided is working to the extent that each 'button' is showing the correct id depending on which table you chose from but i can't figure out why it fails just because of adding the parameters to moveTable (eg.<?php echo $RNrow['request_number']; ?>, 'Approve'). I've tried quoting and un-quoting the id. Does the class have to come into play??

Comment: Check updated code. It should run as a single page. Classes don't matter. On each button, notice onclick="moveTable(x, y).. sends the table id as x, and the status, approve/deny as y. The moveTable script takes that in, then does an ajax call to the script at the bottom of the page, gets that result, and returns it back to the page. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Stay active in posts you started where users are actively helping you.